# Помогите разобраться с запросом REPLACE

Tags: php, sql

Вот сам запрос

```
$query = ("REPLACE INTO`" . DB_PREFIX . "archive_sum_back_newposhta` 
           SET name_sender = '" . $this->db->escape($list_data[$key]['name_sender']). "', 
               sum_back = '" . $this->db->escape($list_data[$key]['sum_back']) . "'
         ");
```

поля в базе

```
id_archive  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
name_sender varchar(255)           UNIQUE
sum_back    varchar(255)
```

Когда так записи не дублируются но id меняться (то есть было 2 записи id=1, id=2 а после добавления повторных записей id меняться на id = 3 id =4)
как исправить что бы id не менялись?

Comment: Приведите конкретный сформированый запрос, а не конструктор. И тот набор данных в базе, который он затрагивает.

Comment: Используйте `insert ... on duplicate key update` вместо replace

Comment: Спасибо за помощь insert ... on duplicate key update это то что надо

Answer (score 2):

продублирую свой ответ с англоязычного сайта

Для Mysql возможны 3 сценария, когда встречается дубль первичного ключа.

Если мы хотим

- пропустить вставку - то используем `INSERT IGNORE`
- удалить существующую строку и вставить новую - [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)
- обновить существующую - [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)